# Reordering Polynomial Column Names Based on Degree

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to reorder column names after expanding using the `poly` function in `R`.

The initial function I wrote looks like this:

```
> sorted_data
X0.1     X1.0     X0.2    X1.1     X2.0     X0.3     X1.2     X2.1     X3.0
1 1.701692 1.071616 2.895755 1.82356 1.148361 4.927683 3.103138 1.954156 1.230602
2 1.720578 1.035489 2.960388 1.78164 1.072238 5.093578 3.065450 1.844869 1.110291

s <- strsplit(substring(colnames(sorted_theta), 2), "\\.")
> s
[[1]]
[1] "0" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "0"

[[3]]
[1] "0" "2"

[[4]]
[1] "1" "1"

[[5]]
[1] "2" "0"

colnames(sorted_data) <- sapply(s, function(x) {
      vec <- c("x", "y", "z")[seq_along(x)]
      x <- as.integer(x)
      y <- rep(vec, rev(x))
      paste(y, collapse = "")
    })

colnames(sorted_data)
[1] "x"   "y"   "xx"  "xy"  "yy"  "xxx" "xxy" "xyy" "yyy"
```

I am now trying to change the variable names to x1 x2, and x3. However, I was hoping to generalize the code to allow for more than just 3 variables. I also wanted to update it to use `^` for the powers such as the following:

```
sorted_data_test <- sorted_data
    colnames(sorted_data_test) <- sapply(s, function(powers) {
      terms <- mapply(function(power, index) {
        if (power == "0") {
          return(NULL)
        } else if (power == "1") {
          return(paste0("x", index))
        } else {
          return(paste0("x", index, "^", power))
        }
      }, powers, seq_along(powers), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
      
      # Filter out any NULL values from the terms list
      terms <- Filter(Negate(is.null), terms)
      
      # Collapse the terms into one string
      paste(terms, collapse = "")
    })
```

However, that gives:

```
print(colnames(sorted_theta_test))
[1] "x2"     "x1"     "x2^2"   "x1x2"   "x1^2"   "x2^3"   "x1x2^2" "x1^2x2" "x1^3"
```

How can I edit my second `sapply` to order the columns in the same way as the first `sapply`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there but just lack of `rev` outside `seq_along(powers)`.

You can try

```
s <- strsplit(substring(colnames(sorted_data), 2), "\\.")
colnames(sorted_data_test) <- sapply(s, function(powers) {
    terms <- mapply(function(power, index) {
        if (power == "0") {
            return(NULL)
        } else if (power == "1") {
            return(paste0("x", index))
        } else {
            return(paste0("x", index, "^", power))
        }
    }, powers, rev(seq_along(powers)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) # <------ here is the minor change

    # Filter out any NULL values from the terms list
    terms <- Filter(Negate(is.null), terms)
    # Sort terms alphabetically
    sorted_terms <- sort(unlist(terms))
    # Collapse the terms into one string
    paste(sorted_terms, collapse = "")
})
```

and you will obtain

```
> sorted_data_test
        x1       x2     x1^2    x2x1     x2^2     x1^3   x2x1^2   x2^2x1
1 1.701692 1.071616 2.895755 1.82356 1.148361 4.927683 3.103138 1.954156
2 1.720578 1.035489 2.960388 1.78164 1.072238 5.093578 3.065450 1.844869
      x2^3
1 1.230602
2 1.110291
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to reorder the names of terms like `x2x1`, `x2x1^2`, and `x2^2x1` to put `x1` before `x2`? So they are `x1x2` and so on

Comment: @AW27 Isn't it depending on the column names of `sorted_data`?

Comment: I added `sorted_terms <- sort(unlist(terms))` and it worked. It seems wrong when I try to do it for higher powers though

Comment: Actually the above worked by putting `sorted_terms` under `terms` and `paste(sorted_terms, collapse = '')`